# Calculate diff() between selected rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with ordered times (in seconds) and a column that is either 0 or 1:

```
       time   bit
index
0      0.24   0
1      0.245  0
2      0.47   1
3      0.471  1
4      0.479  0
5      0.58   1
...    ...    ...
```

I want to select those rows where the time difference is, let's say <0.01 s. But only those differences between rows with bit 1 and bit 0. So in the above example I would only select row 3 and 4 (or any one of them). I thought that I would calculate the diff() of the time column. But I need to somehow select on the 0/1 bit.

Comment: Calculate the difference of the time column. Select rows of dataframe where the time value is <.01 and the bit = 0 or 1

Comment: @A.Kot, yep, I think your algorithm will work: `df.ix[(df.time.diff() < 0.01) & (df.bit != df.bit.shift())]`

Comment: Of course, that is it. By simplifying my problem to the above dataframe, the solution was almost there (although I still didn't see it). Also I limited myself to only apply diff to the time column instead of the whole dataframe. That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the future to answer this one. You can apply a function to the dataframe that finds the indices of the rows that adhere to the condition and returns the row pairs accordingly:

```
def filter_(x, threshold = 0.01):
    indices = df.index[(df.time.diff() < threshold) & (df.bit.diff().abs() == 1)]
    
    mask = indices | indices - 1
    
    return x[mask]

print(df.apply(filter_, args = (0.01,)))
```

Output:

```
    time  bit
3  0.471    1
4  0.479    0
```

Comment: Nice - `mask = indices | indices - 1`